# Validating certificate trust chain on Azure website communicating with secure services

Tags: wcf, azure, certificate, wif, azure-web-app-service

We're having an intermittent issue with a azure website (ASP.NET MVC) that talks to a service that is secured by a security token service.

This website is working fine 99% of the time, but it occasionally starts suffering this problem. Restarting the azure website normally resolves the issue, but then starts happening again an hour or so later.

The error we're basically getting is:

```
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException: ID4257: X.509 certificate '[cert info here]' validation failed by the token handler. 
---> System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException: The X.509 certificate [cert info here] is not in the trusted people store. 
     The X.509 certificate [cert info here] chain building failed. The certificate that was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified. 
     Replace the certificate or change the certificateValidationMode. A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.

   at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.X509CertificateValidator.PeerOrChainTrustValidator.Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.X509CertificateValidatorEx.Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml11.Saml11SecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml11.Saml11SecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)
```

The important thing to note here is that the certificate is definitely valid, with a valid trust chain, built to a standard trusted root authority, and we haven't changed anything!